# Memoize fails when function variable changed

Tags: javascript, lodash, memoization

```js
var fibo = function (x) {
  console.log(x);
  if (x === 1) return 1;
  if (x === 2) return 2;
  return fibo(x - 1) + fibo(x - 2);
};

// fibo = _.memoize(fibo);
var fibom = _.memoize(fibo);
console.log(fibom(5));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Why does `memoize` work when assigned to the original function variable name (as shown in the commented-out code) but not when assigned to a new variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign the memoized function to a new variable, then the recursive calls will still go to the un-memoized version. You need to overwrite the reference like you did in the commented out code.

Answer (score 1):

It because the recursive function is calling the original non-memoized function instead of the memoized function.

If you assign/override the `fibo` function, the `fibo` call inside the original function will call the new memoized function and it works.